# Gravity form - WordPress

Tags: javascript, populate, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms, auto-populate

**Form 1 already has a list of attendees who attended a virtual conference with the following fields:-**

> Fname, Lname, Email

**Form 2 should have 5 questions.**

> Fname, Lname, Email

**A survey question**

**Signature**

An email needs to be sent to **Form** 1 attendee with a personalized link to fill a survey. When they click on this link, From 2 will open.

When an attendee opens the link, the fname, lname and email fields from **Form 1** shall be passed into **Form 2** and should be grayed out for **editing.** Only Survey question **(question 4)** and **Signature** part shall be open to answering.

**Can I do it? Thanks for advance**

Comment: Yes its possible and can be easily done. Read more about it here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/

Comment: I already have attendee list. I want to send them 2nd form link.when they open the link form 1(fname & name) should be passed into 2nd form.

Comment: Yes thats correct. You need to read more about that how to do it in the documentation link i added above.

Answer (score 0):

With [Gravity Forms Easy Passthrough](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-easy-passthrough/) and [Gravity Forms Email Users](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-email-users/), you could send the folks who submitted the first form an email with a link to your second form. This link would contain a secure entry token that could then map any information that user had submitted on the first form in the second form.